# Install Older Ansible on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, python3, pip, ansible

I have installed the latest Ansible using pip3 on Ubuntu 20.04.
After that, even if I installed older Ansible version, it still sees the latest version (2.10.4
)
Here are the outputs and I'm not sure what's going on.. and how to remove the new Ansible and install the older version.
Hope someone can guide me what/where to look and fix this.
Thanks,

```
u2004@ubuntu2004:~$ sudo pip3 uninstall ansible
WARNING: Skipping ansible as it is not installed.

u2004@ubuntu2004:~$ ansible --version
ansible 2.10.4
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/home/u2004/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/u2004/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /home/u2004/.local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) [GCC 9.3.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with Ansible 2.9 and 2.10. You can't cleanly downgrade directly, you'll have to uninstall the `ansible-base` package in addition to uninstalling 2.10 and installing an older ansible version.